# Create a SSIS package to run some Stored Procedures by getting the input from the excel

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS.

My requirement is to run various SP's by based on parameters input from the excel.

| Report1 | Report2 | Report 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 | Value1 |  |
| Value2 | Value2 |  |
| Value3 |  |  |

The above mentioned is the sample excel data where Report1 column contains parameters for first report(first SP), Report2 column contains parameters for second report etc.

I have to first check what all column's have data.

Based on that I should run my stored procedures for particular report by passing the corresponding parameters.

For instance,
In report 1 i have data so i should run the stored precedure for report 1 by passing the parameters

Exec report1 N'one,two,three'

Then in report 2 also i have values, so i should run sp for report 2 with the parameters

In report 3, i do not have values. So i need not run it.

I tried with the script tasks.
but it didn't help

Could someone help me for this?

Comment: Do you have code for what you have tried?  You can import the Excel into staging tables as your first step, then pull the parameters from your stage table and call the SP's.  Once in your stage tables all the rest can be done in strait SQL to pass parameters/verify data is there, validate, etc.

Comment: In execute SQL task, I got the SP Running now. What i have to do is, Based on the excel header, i have to run the report. If the header has report 2, the parameters will be there in that column. I have to pass this parameter, run the report and again store the result in an excel.  maximum of 6 reports will be given in the excel sheet